# Can you or should you use an Electric Cement Mixer to prepare larger quantities of self leveling cement?

Tags: concrete

Can you or should you use an Electric Cement Mixer to prepare larger quantities of self leveling cement?

Comment: well if you _are_ doing a large batch, the mixer helps buy time to get it poured instead of stirring by hand for a longer time (unless you're he-man).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be pretty apprehensive of doing that. The working time of SLC is usually pretty rapid, often under 20 minutes.

With such a short working time, for the quantity using a big mixer, it'll be very challenging to mix, pour, and clean up in that short time window.

If you have a decent team of reliable helpers you could probably pull it off, just be sure everyone knows their role before you start mixing.